# top.window.location.href = "" not working in Chrome & FF

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to שמ IFRAME TAB on the Facebook page with fans gate page
The TAB works with link directly to the server, i put the button like plugin to when users clicked on the like the gate dropped and fans will place in the page. The problem is that when you click on the Like (of the Flagain), page does not get the command to refresh itself and nothing happens ... after searching several places on the net I found this function

```
<body class="body">
<div id="fb-root"></div>

       <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
            FB.init({
                appId :'208195102528120',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml : true, // parse XFBML
                channelUrl : 'http://www.drinkin.co.il/ginger/coupon/coupon_ginger.html', // channel.html file
                oauth : true // enable OAuth 2.0
            });
        </script>

    <script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        window.location.reload();

        if (top.location!= self.location) {
        top.window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat/app_208195102528120";
    }
        });
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <img src="https://www.drinkin.co.il/ginger/coupon/coupon_ginger_gate.jpg" width= "810" height= "1200"  />

<div id="fb">
    <div class="fb-like"><fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat" send="false" layout="button_count" width="200" show_faces="false"></fb:like></div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's good I think but it just does not work on FF & Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.top.location.replace("URL");
```

update:

```
<script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        window.location.reload(); //Remove it

        if (top.location!= self.location) {
        window.top.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat/app_208195102528120");
        }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: you mean that:  f (top.location!= self.location) {
   window.top.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat/app_208195102528120");       ???

Comment: Maybe the problem is elsewhere in the script? I just do not understand the js language so well

Comment: yes: this is - window.top.location.replace("https://facebook.com/gingereilat/app_208195102528120");

:3

Comment: It did not Change the result

Comment: window.location.reload();

in code you reload website = code didn't run line 
 if (top.location!= self.location) { 
window.top.location.replace("URL");}

because your website reloaded and browser cancel every thread in website and reload new document .

Comment: <script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        if (top.location!= self.location) {        window.top.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/gingereilat/app_208195102528120");
        }

        });
    </script>

Comment: It gives the same result my friend